# Vue-router, how to prevent the user back to the login screen pressing the back button in browser?

Tags: browser, authentication, vue.js, vue-router

This code prevents the user back to the login screen by modifying the url, but if they click the back button in the browser, he can go to the login screen even when logged in.

The user data is saved in localstorage 'info' when they are authenticated, and when it exits the localstorage is updated to null

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('info') !== null && to.path == '/login'){
        next(from.fullPath)
    }
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('info') === null && to.path != '/login'){
        next('/login')
    } 
    next()
})
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can listen to back button event using [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

You may add this to your root component (perhaps `App.vue` ?). It listens to back (or forward) button event and redirects if necessary.

```
 mounted() {
    window.onpopstate = event => {
      if (
        window.localStorage.getItem("info") !== null &&
        this.$route.path == "/login"
      ) {
        this.$router.push("/"); // redirect to home, for example
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Nice! Worked, thank you! But is this the best way to do this?

Comment: hmm.. difficult to say.. at least it's the best way that i know =]

Answer (score 13):

It's possible using [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) and [route meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html), which allows to delegate route-specific rules to router file.

`beforeEach` code (eg in `main` file):

```
// Check the user's status, and route rules
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Redirect if user is disallowed to view the page
  const isLogged = !! store.getters.getUser
  if (isLogged && to.meta.disallowAuthed) {
    return router.push('/my-redirect-page')
  }

  return next()
})
```

Route definition (set meta flag `disallowAuthed`):

```
login: {
  path: '/login',
  name: 'login',
  component: TheLoginPage,
  meta: { disallowAuthed: true }
},
```

### Note

Meta field  **does not** propagate from parent route to children - in case if also the check of route's parent `meta` field is required, use this (checks both chosen route's meta and metas of routes at any parent level):

```
const isDisallowAuthed = to.matched.some((route) => route.meta.disallowAuthed)
```

instead of accessing it directly:

```
const isDisallowAuthed = to.meta.disallowAuthed
```

Imho, it's always better to go with this approach in case of dealing with auth logic, since checking against `meta.flag` directly requires mental overhead of remembering this caveat while refactoring Routes file.

Related issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/704

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you meant, feel free to specify the issue more.
But to not go back to `/login`, you would need to replace the history when navigating away from `/login`.

```
next({ 
  path: from.fullPath,
  replace: true,
})
```

This way the browser would navigate back to the previous history entry.

You can read more about this [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the availability of a token assigned during login before routing to login page that way, if the token is not absent, just push the current page back. The code to be added to the login component is below:

```
// check for token availability before login page is created    

      created(){
        if(this.$store.state.token){
          this.$router.push({name: '<same page name>'})
        }
      }
```